# Как отменить всплывающее окно (внутри красного)

Tags: java, android, json

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]**Как отключить всплывающее окно , никак не могу найти это в коде , пример скачан с интернета**

```
private void downloadJSON(final String urlWebService) {

    class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try {
                loadIntoListView(s);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(urlWebService);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                String json;
                while ((json = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(json + "\n");
                }
                return sb.toString().trim();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    DownloadJSON getJSON = new DownloadJSON();
    getJSON.execute();
}

private void loadIntoListView(String json) throws JSONException {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
    String[] stocks = new String[jsonArray.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        stocks[i] = "    From:  " +obj.getString("mylocate") + "     To: " + obj.getString("sendlocate") + "      Name: " + obj.getString("name")       ;
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stocks);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}[![Всплывающее окно][1]][1]
```

Comment: Всмысле текст  вслывающий или что? Скриншот окна можно?

Comment: Извиняюсь , забыл фото прикрепить

Answer (score 0):

Так это у вас всплывает из-за Toast.makeText...
Просто удалите эту строку

Comment: Спасибо большое, как же я не увидел её ))) , да и ещё тупо поиском слов не воспользовался, как же я сглупил , аж стыдно мне стало!